# How to do SPARQL query using bif:regexp_match on Jena

Tags: regex, sparql, jena, virtuoso, apache-jena

I have the following SPARQL query on Virtuoso:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?p, ?title WHERE {
   ?p a ?c.
   ?c rdfs:subClassOf* wd:Q2431196.
   ?p rdfs:label ?title .
   FILTER (bif:regexp_match("^Vamp( [(].*[)])?$", ?title))
}
```

On [this SPARQL endpoint](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql), it works fine. It returns the tv show Vamp and also Vamp (telenovela) as expected.

Now I'm trying to do the same on Java, using Jena API, and it fails as follows.

> Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 10, column 204: Unresolved prefixed name: bif:regexp_match

I found a solution to get rid of the Jena exception, as suggested for `bif:contains`. The query would then be as follows:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?p, ?title WHERE {
   ?p a ?c.
   ?c rdfs:subClassOf* wd:Q2431196.
   ?p rdfs:label ?title .
   ?title <bif:regexp_match> "^Vamp( [(].*[)])?$"
}
```

However, that query does not return any elements as the previous query did. It doesn't return any elements on the SPARQL endpoint web interface either (as the previous query did)

Am I doing something wrong? How can I regex it properly?

ps: using `FILTER REGEX( ?title, "^Vamp( [(].*[)])?$")` works on the web SPARQL endpoint, but throws the following error when on Java/Jena:

> Sep 16, 2015 3:16:32 PM org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorLogger logError
>   SEVERE: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.`

I **think** this error has to do with the `( )` characters..

Comment: It definitely looks like the issue is in the regex, either in your construction or in Virtuoso's interpretation.  I cannot provide an immediate solution, but I can and do suggest you raise the question to a more focused audience -- the [Virtuoso Users mailing list(http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/).

Answer (score 2):

use this      `PREFIX bif:<bif:>`
instead of `PREFIX bif:<>` in for jena.

Comment: Surround your code with backticks (`) or add 4 spaces in front of it (on a seperate line) to show it as code. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

You were right in your regex pattern, just a little editing when it comes to java.

For it to work in java, just put the left parentheses ( after ^ and put the right parentheses ) before $.

Your regex pattern should be like this:

"^(Vamp( [(].*[)])?)$";

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your input but it doesn't work either.
I think virtuoso is not working with the <bif:regexp_match>

Comment: I edited the question to add detail.

The <bif:regexp_match>  approach doesn't return anything on the query in the web interface either.

Comment: on the web interface 


FILTER REGEX(?title,"^(Vamp)(( [(].*[)])?)$")

returns what I expect, but 


?title <bif:regexp_match> "^(Vamp)(( [(].*[)])?)$"

returns nothing

Comment: could you please elaborate on why the parentheses order should affect this?

Comment: the parentheses affects this in java because without it, Vamp wouldn't be included in the pattern that you want to find; therefore making your pattern limited to some matches. Thanks for your replies. Hope i offered some help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following prefix declaration as a workaround.

```
PREFIX bif: <bif:>
```

[Live Link](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschemas%2Fbif%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschema%2Fsparql%2Fextensions%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fvirtuoso.openlinksw.com%2Fdata%2Fturtle%2Fgeneral%2FVirtuosoBIFFunctions%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschema%2Fsparql%2Fextensions%23bif%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Cbif%3A%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20bif%3Acontains%20%27%22Virtuoso%20Linked%20Data%22%27%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%2050&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=30000000) demonstrating workaround in action.

[Live Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor Link](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschemas%2Fbif%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschema%2Fsparql%2Fextensions%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fvirtuoso.openlinksw.com%2Fdata%2Fturtle%2Fgeneral%2FVirtuosoBIFFunctions%23%3E%20%0D%0A%23%20PREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fschema%2Fsparql%2Fextensions%23bif%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20bif%3A%20%3Cbif%3A%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20bif%3Acontains%20%27%22Virtuoso%20Linked%20Data%22%27%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%2050&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=30000000) showcasing workaround.

Ultimately, the URI for the Prefix declaration should be:

```
PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>
```

Which I explain in a [Twitter Thread](https://twitter.com/kidehen/status/1448288977107275780) about the same issue i.e., we are working to rectify the regression associated with the standard prefix declaration above.

Answer (score 0):

Jena will fail to parse your SPARQL as it is invalid. 
The main issue is that bif: is a built in prefix in Virtuoso.
To allow Jena to parse it you need to add

```
PREFIX bif:<>
```

to your query.

Comment: That doesn't work. Not in Jena nor in the web interface. It throws the following exception: 

Exception in thread "main" HttpException: 400 Bad Request
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 11: Prefixes 'sql:' and 'bif:' are reserved for SQL names at (...)

Answer (score 0):

As AndyS answered in [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150728235046/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/22052/change-these-sparql-query-to-jena-codejava-to-make-http-request-to-dbpedia), the problem is that `bif` is a virtuoso-specific feature, So you should use `QueryEngineHTTP` instead of `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`. This will submit your query directly to the endpoint and will not pass it through Jena parser.

```
QueryEngineHTTP query_engine = new QueryEngineHTTP(endpoint, query);
```

Comment: Note that this is also covered in the [Virtuoso Jena Provider documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider#Bypass%20Jena/ARQ%20parser)...